# How to load test a new Java web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, load-testing

Within two months were are going live with a web system coded from scratch. We expect that the current user registration rate (1000/day) will maintain and that the system will present extremely low latency. Though, we do not have the knowledge on how to measure:

- performance bottlenecks in the new code base
- concurrency issues that may arise
- maximum number of concurrent users while maintaining our accepted QoS

Our technology stack is: Spring 3, Hibernate, iBatis, Velocity, Polopoly CMS and Oracle RAC.

Can anyone share his/her experience in load testing a web application? Any pointers to tutorials would also be very much welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have used [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) for generating load, open source and free. Load tests are written in jyhton, very flexible.

Then we use [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) as a profiler to find processing and memory hotspots, and more.

This combination has worked very well for us.